# Flask view function catch all URLs except one small subset

Tags: python, flask

I'm writing a proxy in Flask. The proxy should forward all requests except one small subset, for which some additional checks should be performed. 
Since there is a variety of routes I found this example in the docs 
to match all URLs:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    return 'You want path: %s' % path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

What I'm wondering is what is the best way to have one view function that handles this subset of routes, and another view function that handles all others ?

Answer (score 0):

Flask has decorators to perform action [before handling](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.before_request) the request.

```
@app.after_request
def catch_all(response):
    # * additional checks here *
```

You can stop the normal handling by returning data

> If any of these function returns a value it’s handled as if it was the return value from the view and further request handling is stopped.

It is often use for authentication or permission checks.

Comment: but checks should be performed only for a small subset of routes, not for all. Checks are performed on data sent in the request body, and that data varies in structure for different view functions. For instance one route ( let call it /example) sends an xml which is digitally signed, and the validity of the signature should be checked. Other routes do not send data in the request body, or send data which is different in structure

Comment: Look for blueprint, you can then filter entering request based on blueprint subset.